# Crystal report not showing in application

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have a function that i am using to show crystal reports in my application. Everything was fine until yesterday afternoon and now it is showing nothing but a blank window. But it is not giving any error.In crystal report designer it is showing values while previewing. I am using stored procedure to retrieve values from DB. Here is my code

```
Public Sub ShowReport(ParamArray reportParameters())
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim NTOT As Integer
    Dim nCtr As Integer
    Dim LoopCount As Integer
    Dim ReportPath As String

    Open App.Path & "/Reports.txt" For Input As #1
    Input #1, ReportPath
    Close #1

    ReportPath = ReportPath & "\Reports\" & reportParameters(0)
    'MsgBox ReportPath
    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

    With frmReports.Crpt
        .Reset
        .WindowTop = 0
        .WindowLeft = 0
        .ReportFileName = ReportPath

        '.RetrieveStoredProcParams
        For LoopCount = 3 To UBound(reportParameters)
            .StoredProcParam(LoopCount - 3) = reportParameters(LoopCount)
        Next

       .WindowTitle = reportParameters(1)
       .ReportTitle = reportParameters(1)
       .WindowParentHandle = frmReports.hwnd
       .WindowShowSearchBtn = True
       .WindowShowPrintSetupBtn = True
       .WindowShowRefreshBtn = True
       .WindowShowProgressCtls = True
       .WindowShowZoomCtl = True
       .WindowShowGroupTree = True
       .WindowAllowDrillDown = True
       .ProgressDialog = True
       .PageZoom (100)
       .WindowState = crptMaximized

       If reportParameters(2) = "P" Then
           .Destination = crptToPrinter
       Else
           .Destination = crptToWindow
       End If
       .Action = 1
End With

Screen.MousePointer = vbNormal

Exit Sub
Catch:
    Screen.MousePointer = vbNormal
End Sub
```

I am using VB6 and crystal reports version is 8
what is wrong in this code? Can anyone find a solution for this